# Tkinter Entry fields with mysql commands to create new databases

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, tkinter

here is what I am trying to do I have created entry fields so that a user may connect to a mysql server. This is working as intended, but what I would also like to do is allow authorized users to create and add new databases and tables if needed.

When using mysql, how would I use .get() to capture user input for names of DB's and tables?

Below is how I have my function coded currently this is going to be a command eventually. I have consulted my Mysql book, but it doesn't help me much in the way of gui programming.

Example:

```
def createdb():
    conn=mysql.connect(
        host=ho_ent.get(),
        user=us_ent.get(),
        passwd=pa_ent.get()
        )
    c=conn.cursor()
    c.execute("CREATE DATABASE db_ent.get()")

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

I tested it, and this clearly does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: `"CREATE DATABASE " + db_ent.get()`.

Comment: @acw1668 this worked flawlessly thanks! I couldn't remember how to combine this properly.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an `Entry` widget, to retrieve the content you need to use the `.get()` method, like you said.

It seems you are using it here:

```
conn=mysql.connect(
        host=ho_ent.get(),
        user=us_ent.get(),
        passwd=pa_ent.get()
        )
```

I am not familiar with SQL, so I don't know if `.get()` is a method there as well. I will assume it is.

Say you have an `Entry` `e = Entry(master)`.

To retrieve the contents of it, you can do this:

```py
def retrieve():
    print(e.get())
```

When you call `retrieve()`, you get the contents.

Hope this helps!